# how to reduce the space between icon and a text in a raisedbutton.icon widget?

Tags: flutter

i would like to reduce the space which exists between an icon and a text inside a raisedbutton

[image]

here is what i have tried to do:

```
            RaisedButton.icon(onPressed: (){
                    (product.hasAbonnement=false) ?
                    Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ProductDetailPage(
              product: product,
              viewModel: widget.viewModel,),
      ))
        :
          Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SubcriptionDetailPage(
              product: product,
              viewModel: widget.viewModel,),
      ));

      }, icon: Icon(Icons.add,color: Colors.white), label:Text('S\'abonner',
      style:TextStyle(color:Colors.white,
      )
     ,),
     clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
     shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
    ),
    color:mmpataColorBlue,
      ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution, as **Hiwa Jalal** has given the right answer, just a bit of manipulation required. Here you go:

```
Center(
   child: RaisedButton(
     color: Colors.blue,
     shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
     ),
     child: Row(
       mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
       children: <Widget>[
         Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white), 
         Text('S\'abonner', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
       ]
     ),
     onPressed: () {}
   )
)
```

Output:

[image: Screenshot of the Result]

Answer (score 0):

you can use the default `RaisedButton` constructor and make it's child a `Row` then you can provide the space you want between the children widget using a `SizedBox`, for example:

```
RaisedButton(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.add),
            SizedBox(width: 20), // give the width that you desire 
            Text('S\'abonner')
          ],
        ),
        onPressed: () {},
      )
```

Comment: i did it but  the button takes the whole line width

Comment: then use `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` in your row.

Comment: @hiwajalal Update you answer to include mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min